# Traefik dashboard and API return 404

Tags: docker, traefik

I am currently learning how to work with Traefik. My goal is to deploy Traefik, Postgres and my backend API to docker swarm.

When I try to deploy Traefik with API and dashboard enabled I am not able to access the dashboard and API.
I have the following config file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.3.4
    command:
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik-public"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--api.debug=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
        # Dummy service for Swarm port detection. The port can be any valid integer value.
        - "traefik.http.services.dummy-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9999"
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

Before deploying this file I did the following setup:

1. docker swarm init
2. docker network create --driver=overlay traefik-public

What do I need to add or who can I create a working local setup? I also tried to replace localhost with "traefik.local", 127.0.0.1, and my local IP address, but nothing of this is working.

I am also not able to deploy another API and access it over Traefik.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First time working with Traefik as well, and I experienced a similar 404 issue.

Turns out in my case it was down to making a https request where there was no https router. Might be the same in your case as I can see you also set the `--api.insecure` config parameter to true. [The documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/faq/#404-not-found) might provide some help if that is not the case or you want to know more.